# I have a problem about updating in terminal

Tags: package-management, ppa

Here is the link, please help me what it means below:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
```

What should I do with the link above

Comment: General hint: If you include the complete terminal output from the  command you used typed into terminal to the command prompt after it fails, that often helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly you gave a general link to the http://ppa.launchpad.net site as opposed to the specific one I am sure you meant to.

However, easy fix.

When I run into a PPA and I can't get the PUBKEY, I wrote a little something, or borrowed, it, I don't remember, and I even made it an alias to throw it into my `.bashrc` so I can simply hit a few letters.

Here is the code.

```
alias pubkey="for i in `sudo aptitude update 2>&1 | grep NO_PUBKEY | awk '{print $NF;}'`; do sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys $i; done"
```

As you can see, it searches for missing pubkeys and then sends off to the keyservers at ubuntu to update your system witht hem.  Trust me, run this and you will be alright.

Throw that into your `.bashrc`, then type `source .bashrc` and finally `pubkey` and all your worries are over.

Just make sure you have aptitude installed first, just a quick `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and you will be fine.